# jQuery Infinite Scroll's loading fires too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I tried to implement [jQuery Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/). But the loading fires too early. At first, it fires even if I only scroll the page 1 pixel. And then it still fires far before I scroll the page to the bottom.

At first, I make an Ajax call to fill in the first page. Then I initialize Infinite Scroll. As following.

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'data/page1.html',
    cache    :  true,
    dataType : 'html',
    success  :  function(newElements) {
        $('#container')
            .append(newElements)
            .infinitescroll({
                 // -- selector for: --
                 navSelector  : '#pagenav', // the paged navigation 
                 nextSelector : '#pagenav', // the NEXT link (to page 2)
                 itemSelector : '.item',    // all items you'll retrieve
                 // --
                 loading      :  { 
                     finishedMsg: 'No more items to load', 
                     img: 'images/ajax-loading.gif' 
                 }
            });
    }
});
```

<s>I had simplified my files at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwkLXIVz0y59eTktMWl3bE9xd2c/view) for demonstration purpose.</s>

EDIT: [Demonstration on Plunker](http://goo.gl/boZdhW).

Comment: how about set a timeout inside success.

Comment: @pkrawat1: Not sure what that means, but I tried putting `setTimeout(function() { $('#container').append(newElements) }, 0)` inside success and nothing changed.

Comment: i was saying that you could delay the process by giving it a delay of 1000ms or so.

Comment: did u try tweaking bufferPx     : 40 ?

Comment: @user1428716: Hi, I just tried it, and it is still the same.

Comment: Is it not by design? If a scroll bar reaches the bottom, you delay your user from proceeding. I have a fast mouse wheel and I was never blocked by this user interface. I think it is okay, so why do you want to slow down the advance loading?

Comment: @ThisClark: It's not by design, please check the official demo file. The official demo fires the loading only when user scrolls to the bottom, by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#container').infinitescroll({
    dataType: 'html',
    appendCallback: false,
    navSelector: '#pagenav', // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector: '#pagenav', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector: '.item',
    pixelsFromNavToBottom: 50
  });

});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOmQTTZMEByvJrUtn8Bp?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

After checking the source code, I found [on line 423](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js#L423) that the loading has something to do with the position of navigation. Then I realized that I hid navigation by setting `display: none;` to it in my CSS that caused the script to be unable to calculate the position of navigation correctly. After removing `display: none;`, the problem has been fixed.

Thank everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "data/page1.html",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(newElements) {
      setTimeout((function() {
        $("#container").append(newElements).infinitescroll({
          navSelector: "#pagenav",
          nextSelector: "#pagenav",
          itemSelector: ".item",
          loading: {
            finishedMsg: "No more items to load",
            img: "images/ajax-loading.gif"
          }
        });
      }), 5000);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it is still the same. P.S. I had moved my demonstration onto Plunker so that everyone could see it in action immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was looking for an infinite scroll plugin, so I ended up using [Endless Scroll](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll).

The good thing about this plugin is that you can define options, such as 'bottomPixels', as shown in the following example:

```
$(document).endlessScroll({
    bottomPixels: 300,
    fireDelay: 200,
    callback: function() {
        if ($('#table').length > 0 && !loadedAllEntries && !loadPending) {
            loadEntries($('#table tbody tr').size());
        }
    },
    ceaseFire: function() {
        if (loadedAllEntries) 
            return 1;

        if ($('#table').length === 0)
            return 2;
    }
});
```

I set loadPending to true in the beginning of every request so that only one request is active for every given moment. Hope this helps.